# Cant run my cron job

Tags: laravel-5, cron

I have made a cron job for backing up my database.

When i run `php artisan backup:database`,
I have an error showing that `"App\Console\Commands\Storage"` is missing.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUYYCx3eFfA) video on youtube. And this video is 3 years back.

Can someone help me with this error. Or is there any other alternative to backup database?

Below is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class DatabaseBackup extends Command
{    
    protected $signature = 'backup:database';    
    protected $description = 'This is to backup database';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y');
        $user = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $command = "mysqldump --user={$user} -p{$password} {$database} > {$date}.sql";
        $process = new Process($command);
        $process->start();
        while ($process->isRunning()) {
           $public = Storage::disk('public');
           $public->put('users/'.$date.".sql", file_get_contents("{$date}.sql"));
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to add

```
use Storage;
```

And also changed the date format to d-m-Y. It works now!

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class DatabaseBackup extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'backup:database';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This is to backup database';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
        $user = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $command = "mysqldump --user={$user} -p{$password} {$database} > {$date}.sql";
        $process = new Process($command);
        $process->start();
        while ($process->isRunning()) {
           $public = Storage::disk('public');
           $public->put('users/'.$date.".sql", file_get_contents("{$date}.sql"));
        }

    }
}
```